# Why am I not warned if I upvote a new answer before trying to accept it?

Tags: bug, voting, accepted-answer

If I upvote *then* attempt to accept an answer immediately after it is posted to my question, I get a message that says "you can accept an answer in *x* minutes."

If I attempt to accept *then* upvote an answer immediately after it is posted to my question, I get no such message.

Why does the error get shown when upvoting before attempting to accept the answer, but not when upvoting after attempting to accept the answer?

Comment: That is a know bug as well, but maybe I only have a dupe on MSE

Comment: I recall it is an race condition server-side but I can't find the post anymore.

Comment: You did not specify whether trying to accept the answer before upvoting works or not. If it does work obviously there's no point in showing the message.

Comment: uh, Peter, that's not how semicolons work

Comment: @underscore_d: I am applying [*3.2 Sentences* in *How to improve your writing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Tony1/How_to_improve_your_writing#Sentences), perhaps incorrectly?

Comment: Peter: AFAIK, the rule-of-thumb for a semicolon is that either side/clause could be a separate sentence (with only punctuation/capitalisation changing). But it often gets misused as a 'clever' way of pausing, with a longer delay than a comma - where people should probably use a dash instead. To be fair, the original sentence is unclear & so not easy to correct. But I think it should probably be `But if I do the opposite - that is, accept the answer before upvoting - it doesn't show this message` or `But if I accept the answer before upvoting, this doesn't happen; it doesn't show this message.`

Comment: *"When someone replies to my question, I immediately try to upvote, and make it as an accepted answer"* Just to be sure: you're upvoting and accepting good and helpful answers (accepting the most helpful one) and not just any answer, just because they answered ... something, right?

Comment: @Tom: Usually I upvote immediately If I think my question isn't that great  and ofcourse the answer has to be helpful:)

Comment: Definitely `;` misuse there @PeterMortensen

Comment: Rather than being a race condition, it may be as simple as your second click when trying to upvote dismisses the message pop-up.

Comment: Also comma misuse.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *Also, comma misuse.* ;)